# How can I select/print an element of a subarray of an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Hope you can help me on this one. I have this php array variable.

```
$countries = [
"Argentina" => ['Buenos Aires','Cordoba','Rosario'],
"USA" => ['San Fransisco','Dallas','Nueva Yotk'],
"Brasil" => ['Rio','San Pablo','Salvador']
```

and I want to print, for example:  Argentina, Córdoba  or USA, Nueva York, etc.
I mean, select one element of one of the subarrays. How can I accomplish that? I've tried

```
print_r(array_values($countries));
```

it prints ALL values, but I want to print a specific value of the key/s

Thanks!

Comment: Try `echo($countries['USA'][0]);`, `echo($countries['USA'][1]);`, etc. Probably should read: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Getting the index of a element from a array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764654/php-getting-the-index-of-a-element-from-a-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$countries = [
    "Argentina" => ['Buenos Aires','Cordoba','Rosario'],
    "USA" => ['San Fransisco','Dallas','Nueva Yotk'],
    "Brasil" => ['Rio','San Pablo','Salvador']
];
```

In the array above, `Argentina`, `USA`, `Brasil` are the array keys. To get to array keys, you can make use of function `array_keys();`

Code:

```
$keys = array_keys($countries);
print_r($keys);
```

Output:

> Array ( [0] => Argentina [1] => USA [2] => Brasil )

To reach specific value of specific key, you can:

```
echo $countries['Argentina'][0]
```

Output:

> Buenos Aires

You can also access it with key index, as `$keys` is also an array as:

```
echo $countries[$keys[1]][1];
```

Output:

> Dallas

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking for something like:
    echo $countries[$keys[1]][1];